# How to explain visitors that we don't control Google's results?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, cache

I have a message boards. Once in a while, some people contact us to remove anything related to them. We comply and delete all the posts and all traces. Some of those visitors still complain that they still appear on Google.

What can I tell them? Is there a link on Google explaining the whole cache thing, how often they update, etc ...

I'm looking for a canned answer that would shift the responsibility away from me.

Comment: +1 - some people are beyond uneducated when it comes to the web. I once had someone threaten to sue me because I sent them a prank link from a website that used to exist called `isgay.com` - `fname.lname.isgay.com` would load a fake news artical outing them as gay. Amusing for a teenager, but some people just go too far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some related information from Google themselves:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164133&cbid=-a2l7h00q1r9q&src=cb&lev=%20answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way to communicate this is to liken it to the Postal system. If you change addresses you let the post office know, but it's up to them to make sure the mail gets to your new location.